# Unique ID's in TD Table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm confusing for TD tag in HTML, in Input tag we have `name` as unique ID's for state the ID's of the input box but what is the unique ID's in TD replace for `name` attribute? Because when I updating my form, all are from Input tag are updated but in TD tag not updating because there is no specific/unique ID to send the data.

My code as below:

**Input Tag**

```
<input name="four" type="text" class="style6" value="<?php echo $row['four']; ?>" size="3">
```

**TD Attribute**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<center>
<?php echo $row['one'] = round($row['two'] / $row['three']); ?>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are u refreshing the page via ajax?

Comment: what so you mean by java? I'm using javascript in my code

Comment: then what's the issue man using javascript u can use document.getElementbyId("id of td")

Comment: I don't know how to use it, can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute in `input` is not required to be unique. It is used to make the element contribute to the form data and provide a name for the contribution (name=value).

The `td` element does not contribute to form data. The `name` attribute is invalid for it, and the `id` attribute, though allowed (as for any element), does not affect functionality. Table cell markup does not affect form data at all. You need form fields for that.

Comment: in Input tag, we have `name` as an ID's and `value` as what data that we want to send, but in TD I know know where to put the ID's.

Comment: @mastersuse, it does not matter whether a `td` element has an `id` attribute or not. It still does not send data. The `input` elements are used for sending data. You may need to explain the original problem, as now it seems that you have a wrong approach (trying to make `td` elements input fields, instead of just being containers for them).

Comment: You're correct, I've tested that TD's does not send data, it's also not update the data.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can simply try as

```
<td id="someid"></td>


<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementbyid("someid").innerHTML = "whatever you want to put inside it"
</script>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I do as above, is this true? I'm sorry because I'm not good in PHP.                 `<td id="one"><?php echo $row['one'] = round($row['two'] / $row['three']); ?></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementbyid("one").innerHTML = "<?php echo $row['one'] = round($row['two'] / $row['three']); ?>"
</script>`

Comment: or like this? `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementbyid("percent_appt_today").innerHTML = "percent_appt_today"</script>` and at table tag `<td id="percent_appt_today">
   <?php echo $row['one'] = round($row['two'] / $row['three']); ?>
   </td>`